# Twig auto import macros by environment

Tags: twig

Is it possible (and how) to automatically include specific macro files into every twig file by using PHP (not Twig lang).

> Example: I got the file select2 which contains macros to define
>   select2 selections. Now the Twig environment autoincludes every macro
>   in that file under select2.macroname and without calling import in
>   other twig files I can use that macro?

I'm using twig standalone.

Comment: U can't. They changed the behavior so you would need to include the macro in every file you use. See [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/deprecated.html#macros)

Comment: That applies on imports in twig files I thought and not if I extend my TwigEnvironment. Is it possible to compile macros and them inject them as a global twig function/variable? and if so can you give me a hint?

Comment: Never thought of that aproach. Seems to work though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U could inject the file containing the macro's as a global variable into `twig`

```
$twig->addGlobal('my_macros', $twig->loadTemplate('macros.html'));
```

---

*macros.html*

```
{% macro HelloWorld(foo) %}
    {{ foo }}
{% endmacro %}
```

*random_file.html*

```
{{ my_macros.HelloWorld('StackOverflow') }} {# output: StackOverflow #}
```

---

**UPDATE April 2022**

If you are looking for a method to auto-load macros in `twig 3.X` then have a look at the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71937128/446594)

Comment: I will try it, but am I able to call it like {{ macros.select('a','b'...) }}?

Comment: omg realy obvisiuos thank you very much (thanks for the detailed example)